# VB6 exe not same in VSourceSafe after checking in

Tags: vb6, visual-sourcesafe

We started using VSS integrated with vb6 at our company, one problem we have is that the visual basic project file's make-version-number doesn't get updated after making an exe.

Other form/code files do update though.
What could be the reason & workaround for the .vbp file not updating?

Thanks

Comment: What's "make-version-number"? Do you check-out the .vbp file before compiling?

Comment: In the .vbp properties there is a version number in the Make tab.

Comment: The version number has Major/Minor/Revision numbers. I've set it to automatically auto increment, but it doesn't get changed on the server when checking in.

Comment: If the .vbp is not read-only it does get incremented when compiled from command line with `vb6.exe /make my.vbp /out my.log`. How do you compile your projects?

Comment: Have you manually saved the project AFTER compiling? It needs to be saved before the updated build number is written to disk.

Comment: I set vb6 so it saves before compiling (ie it always asks and I say yes to save). I compile from within the IDE.

Comment: @dimitarie: The option is to save before run. You need to save the project manually (or exit and save) for the updated build number to be written to the project file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the project is in the VSS and is checked out before you save it.

Make sure you are checking in the right VBP file.

When you compile, before checking in, does the revision number change in the Project Properties?

---

### EDIT 1 (October 29, 2012):

---

Please follow the steps below and tell me the result:
- Check out the project (including VBP file, make sure you get the latest version from SourceSafe)

- Open VBP, the Auto Increment option is checked and Version Number section has valid numbers (Major/Minor/Revision)
- Work on the project, compile EXE, check if Version Number section has new Revision number
- Check in all files (including VBP) into SourceSafe
- Close project
- Get latest VBP file from the SourceSafe, open it, check version number numbers

---

Comment: It does change, but when checking in, it doesn't change the vbp on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to "auto increment build number" enabled, then you will need to make sure the project is saved AFTER compiling before checking it in to source control.

You can do one of:

1. Manually save the project after compiling.
2. Exit the IDE and choosing to save the project afterwards.
3. Right click the VBP and compile from the context menu. This will compile and save the project automatically.

The project file also needs to be writable (i.e. not readonly or checked in) for these to save correctly.